# Can I create MySQL View with SHOW keywords?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create view like

```
 create view GetProcessList
 as
 show processlist
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can just query the [`processlist` table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-processlist-table.html), which `show processlist` is based on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible?

No you can only create a view base on a SELECT statement , not a SHOW statement. But if your question is really how you can access the processlist as if it were a table....then this is already available in the information_schema meta-database:

```
MariaDB [information_schema]> SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST;
+----+------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------+
| ID | USER | HOST      | DB                 | COMMAND | TIME | STATE                | INFO                                         | TIME_MS | STAGE | MAX_STAGE | PROGRESS | MEMORY_USED | EXAMINED_ROWS | QUERY_ID |
+----+------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 42 | root | localhost | information_schema | Query   |    0 | Filling schema table | SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST |   0.561 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |       83104 |             0 |      204 |
+----+------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```